# Big Sur Security Update 11.7.2 broke my OS and I can't install helper tools

Tags: macos, finder, install, big-sur

I can't install any helper tools after installing a security update and it's preventing me from running my programs.

This is what I've tried:

1. First Aid recovery mode and while running the system (Tried the latter out of desperation)
2. Reinstalled BigSur again over the top of my current installation.
3. Tried adding my user and changing everyone (except wheel) to have read/write privs on the folder "PrivilegedHelperTools" recursively.
4. Uninstalled Bit Defender and turned off Little Snitch.

---

What happened prior to this problem is:

I restarted my mac one day and my mac would not make it to the finder.  The progress bar would hang halfway and then reboot.  This kept happening in loop until I saw a kernal panic, and then, the Contact Apple Support screen. After entering the system with safemode, I was able to download the new Big Sur Update 11.7.2 and my system booted up again, but with these issues.

Does anybody know why I can't install ANY helper tools anymore and how I can get around this issue?  I've tried everything within the scope of my knowledge. Apple just wants me to wipe and start again, but I can't as I have hundreds of Audio Plugin authorisations and i'm worried i'm going to lose them.  It happened once before when time machine did not back these up.

Thanks kindly, SINCd

Comment: Make a new admin account & test in there, in case it's account-specific.

Comment: Also, text the problem in Safe Boot mode. It is highly unlikely that a Security Update 'broke' your Mac. Most likely, you've got some old software running in the background that needs updating. Which Helper Tools are you trying to install?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks so much for getting back.  

@Tetsujin - Yes tried with a new user but the problem persisted.

Comment: Precisely what helper tools are you trying to install? What error do you get? Are you sure they're compatible with Big Sur?

Comment: @benwiggy I had also tried in safe mode but the problem persisted.  The reason why I said the update broke my OS was that prior to this, I had no problem installing helper tools. When the OS booted after the security update, so many programs were popping up on launch complaining about security permissions.  If I went into security, unlocked and tried to re-tick those apps, it wouldn't let me tick them. I removed them and re-added them, then I could tick. After reboot, going back to Security/Privacy, the programs were missing and boxes could not be ticked still. None of this was an issue b4.

Comment: Hmmm… it sounds like you should reinstall the OS from Recovery. This shouldn't touch any user areas.

Comment: I'm not trying to install helper tools.  The programs I'm running, need to install these helpers again for some reason.  Protools, Native Access, App Tamer.  These were all programs installed previously working fine.  I got around the others because I was able to run an installer and that got some of my programs reworking. Other programs like Native Access, don't have a .pkg installer and are just an app you drop into the Applications folder, and then upon launch, it asks to install the required helper tool.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, I had done that already (reinstalled the OS)

Comment: I'm wondering if my Security/Privacy prefs somewhere is part of the problem, because it won't retain my ticks or won't let me tick some at all.

Comment: @Tetsujin hey, I DID mention, I installed the update and ALSO reinstalled the system as part of my troubleshooting. Sorry if that wasn't clear enough.  First time posting here. I do appreciate your help and trying to narrow it down.

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry - I missed it for some reason. My bad.

Comment: I do understand your paranoia re plugins. I had a rig where the plugin authorisation server was no longer in existence, so I couldn't afford to lose anything. I'm actually still on Mojave for plugin/hardware drivers/software that still have 32-bit components. Most companies have rapid reauthorisation routines, though - assuming they still exist.

Comment: Are you sure they need to install the Helper Tools again, or just authorise them? What exact message are you seeing? Pro Tools and Native Access should work fine on Monterey and Ventura.

Comment: Hey thank you and sorry I missed this.  Every time I install native access, it asks to install a helper tool. Then gets stuck on dependencies. Even after talking with NI customer support and using their suggestions and terminal commands, I'm still stuck in this loop.  I'm on BigSur which qualifies but am considering upgrading to Monteray once I feel my system is stable and working again.  I re-installed the latest protools update which resolved ProTools complaining.